# drupal 7 download PDF after form submit

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

records display using views, which display white paper information with following fields.
1. white paper Title
2. white paper Description
3. Show download link.

now i want to make following thing.

When click the download link, need to show the form in popup (WEB FORM), after form submitted, need to download the PDF file.

note: each download link have different PDF files.

[image: file the form to download the PDF]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Drupal usage, belongs to http://drupal.stackexchange.com